# Monitor Nginx and Docker using google-stackdriver

Tags: docker, nginx, monitoring, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have few servers which is on premise. I need to monitor Nginx and Docker containers using stackdriver. I installed the monitoring agent from GCP and I'm having difficulties in configuring it. I'm actually new to this monitoring and logging in GCP, If someone can help me or post some articles related to this it would be so helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I think it would help if you described more of the details of what you are trying to achieve, what you have already studied, what you have tried and the outcome.  The documentation for Stackdriver can be found here ... 

https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/

Comment: I'm confident that you'll be unable to run the agent off-cloud. IIUC the agent supports only GCP and AWS VMs. Stackdriver currently is not well-suited to monitoring on-premises services. https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/#supported_vms

Comment: @kolban My main aim is to monitor the JVM heap sizes inside docker containers, that means monitor docker memory usages via google-stackdriver. All the dockers are there in on-prem servers not in any cloud provider.

Comment: @DazWilkin GCP has given a script to install the monitoring agent, I used it to install it and run in my off-cloud environment. Agent runs, But I'm kinda clueless on how to configure it.